# Add 2 JTextPane to one scrollPane

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I am trying to add 2 JTextPane to one scrollPane. But it not scrolling. What am I doing wrong?

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(402, 211, 178, 193);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
panel.setLayout(null);

JTextPane textPane_branding = new JTextPane();
textPane_branding.setBounds(98, 0, 78, 191);
panel.add(textPane_branding);

JTextPane textPane_trunk = new JTextPane();
textPane_trunk.setBounds(0, 0, 88, 191);
panel.add(textPane_trunk);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here. If you want both of your `JTextPane` to be scrollable you need to put each one into its own `JScrollPane`. That would look like this:

```
JTextPane textPane_branding = new JTextPane();
JScrollPane scroll_branding = new JScrollPane(textPane_branding);
scroll_branding.setBounds(98, 0, 78, 191);
panel.add(scroll_branding);

JTextPane textPane_trunk = new JTextPane();
JScrollPane scroll_trunk = new JScrollPane(textPane_trunk);
scroll_trunk.setBounds(0, 0, 88, 191);
panel.add(scroll_trunk);
```

If you want both of your `JTextPane` being into one `JPanel` that is scrollable I'm wondering why you set fixed `Bounds` to your `JScrollPane` and to the `JTextPanes`. That makes Scrolling absurd here. And thats why `JScrollPanes` don't work with Panes that don't have Layouts and use fixed Bounds. Also it is very bad practise.
So I would suggest here to stay with a Layout Manager in your `JPanel` and use `setPreferredSize` with your `JTextPanes` to define your desired Dimensions. And then your `JScrollPane` will start working.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
//scrollPane.setBounds(402, 211, 178, 193);  // Don't do this!
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
//panel.setLayout(null);                     // Use a Layout Manager

JTextPane textPane_branding = new JTextPane();
textPane_branding.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(78,191));
//textPane_branding.setBounds(98, 0, 78, 191);
panel.add(textPane_branding);

JTextPane textPane_trunk = new JTextPane();
textPane_trunk.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(88,191));
//textPane_trunk.setBounds(0, 0, 88, 191);
panel.add(textPane_trunk);
```